Generating function condition not satisfied?
We want to find a generating function $S(q_i,P_i,t)$ such that we get the best possible canonical transformations. So it must satisfy the Hamilton-Jacobi equation:
$$H(q_i,\frac{\partial S}{\partial q_i},t)+\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=0.\tag{1}$$ Let's even take the easier case where the hamiltonian is time-independent. Then we can search for the Hamilton's principal function in the form:
$$S(q_i,P_i,t)=W(q_i,P_i)-\alpha_0t.\tag{2}$$
However from the theory of canonical transformations we know that in order for a generating function to work it has to satify the following condition:
$$F(t_2)-F(t_1)=0.\tag{3}$$
Well in our case we have:
$$S(q_i(t_2),P_i,t_2)-S(q_i(t_1),P_i,t_1)=W(q_i(t_2),P_i)-W(q_i(t_1),P_i)-\alpha_0(t_2-t_1).\tag{4}$$
My question is how are we ensuring that this is equal to zero always? And maybe thinking about it I don't understand how do we ensure this in any canonical transformation not just the Hamilton-Jacobi equation. How are
we sure what the functions values will be before knowing the trajectory as a function of time?

More precisely, where did condition (3) come from?

@Qmechanic When deriving the canonical transformation we say that the variations of the lagrangians must be equal so that $\delta \int_{t_0}^{t_1}(\sum p_i\dot{q_i}-H(q_i,p_i,t))dt=\delta \int_{t_0}^{t_1}(\sum P_i\dot{Q_i}-K(Q_i,P_i,t)+\frac{dF}{dt})dt$. So If we want to preserve hamilton's equations that come from the variational principle (the transformation to be canonical), then F must satisfy condition $(3)$


OP's condition (3) is not there/not necessary. Instead a type-2 generating function $F_2(q,P,t)$ satisfies the following $2n+1$ conditions:
$$ p_j~=~\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial q^j},\qquad Q^j~=~\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial P_j},\qquad K-H~=~\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial t}. \tag{9.17}$$

For a Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ without explicit time dependence,
OP seems to ponder how the Hamilton's principal function $S(q,P,t)$ and the Hamilton's characteristic function $W(q,P)$ can both serve the role as an $F_2(q,P,t)$ generating function if we also identify$^1$
$$ S(q,P,t)~=~W(q,P)-P_1 t~?\tag{10.17}$$

The resolution is to pick the Kamiltonian differently in the 2 cases:
$$ K_S~:=~0\quad\text{and}\quad K_W~:=~P_1. $$


References:

H. Goldstein, Classical Mechanics; section 10.3.


$^1$ Note that the constants of integration $\alpha_j$ are identified with the new momenta $P_j$, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.
